# Is it possible to create a second application in a windows form application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Sometimes I have problems with reseting all the values that the main application uses. So I want to create a second application which is executed by the main application so that I can refresh the second application whitout exiting the main one.

Comment: You mean instantiate a new form?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Please elaborate.

Comment: You can make 2 windows form on the same application/project and run the 2nd one on background or bring it to front as u wish

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Currnetly I am doing that. Considering exception handler popups, help popup error popups I have almost 10 forms added to my project. It is gone the way out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would launch the second application as a separate process, using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start).